# AWS SAM: MinimumCompressionSize property doesn't work on Lambda responses for AWS::Serverless::Api

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sam, aws-rest-api

According to the AWS SAM Template Documentation, you can specify a [`MinimumCompressedSize`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-api.html#sam-api-minimumcompressionsize) attribute for `AWS::Serverless::API` resources which should compress response bodies which exceed a given threshold, yet in local testing this doesn't work.

Take for instance a slightly modified `node v16` "Hello-World" project generated using `sam init`:

`template.yaml`:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  sam-app

  Sample SAM Template for sam-app
  Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3
    MemorySize: 128
Resources:
  CompressedApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: "Prod"
      MinimumCompressionSize: 0
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello-world/
      Handler: app.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs16.x
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api 
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: get
            RestApiId: !Ref CompressedApi
```

And the corresponding node code for app.lambdaHandler:

```js
exports.lambdaHandler = async (event, context) => {
    try {
        // const ret = await axios(url);
        response = {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': JSON.stringify({
                message: 'hello world',
                // location: ret.data.trim()
            })
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return err;
    }

    return response
};
```

After running `sam local start-api` and opening `127.0.0.1:3000/hello` I should expect (if my browser sends an `Accept-Encoding` header with gzip, deflate, or identity compression) to see a compressed response, even for a small payload of 25 bytes since my `MinimumCompressionSize` is set to zero.

Instead I get a uncompressed response:

[image]

**Why doesn't the lambda function response get compressed?  Did I make some mistake in composing this `template.yaml`?**

Note: I'm aware it's possible to setup gzip compression using an HttpApi resource (instead of the Api type used here) by having the lambda function itself compress the response body using a process like the one described in this [blog post](https://maxrohde.com/2022/07/30/enabling-compression-for-lambda-with-aws-http-apis), but my understanding is that this type of Api resource should support this out-of-the-box and there's some mistake I'm making in setting up my application.

Comment: Try changing the message from 'hello world' to 'aaaaa aaaaa' and see if the compression is triggered.   There is not much repetition in hello world and therefore nothing to compress

Comment: @BAbali no luck :(